# In function - Error: Assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

Hi I am initializing a function pointer to replace a switch statement in a boolean function. So i wanted to use a member of the structure and assign/copy address of a boolean function to this member. My later plan is to remove the switch cases and use function pointer to handle specific types (TYPE_A... etc)

```
//Declaration of typedef as a boolean 
typedef bool (*tone_function_t) (state_t *state, u8_t type);

//typedef structure
typedef struct node {
    tone_function_t tone;
} node_t;

bool_t tone(state_t *state, u8_t type) {
    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_A :
        case TYPE_B :
        case TYPE_C :
        case TYPE_D :
        case TYPE_E :
            return TRUE;
    }
  
    return FALSE;
}

int main(state_t *state) {
    node_t node;
    node.tone = &tone; //Compilation Error : assignment from incompatible pointer type. Am i doing any mistake here??
    return 0;
}
```

I am stuck with the compilation error while assigning the address of a boolean function to a member of a struct. Any clue to solve this? Also node->tone is a wrong way to initialize.
Tried memcpy or malloc. It didn't really work.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tone` function doesn't match the pointer type.

`tone` is declared to return a `bool_t` but the function pointer type `tone_function_t` returns a `bool`.

Change one of the two so the return types match.

Comment: I still have same compilation error even after changing.

Comment: @revanth Then there's more going on that you're not showing us.  Please update your code with a [mcve] that others can compile without modification to get the same result you do.

Comment: Your answer was correct. I was experimenting with new things in the code and forgot to few things to change back for ex:     tone_function_t *tone; (removed * now)
Now it worked. Thanks :)